# How to add a value to request header in h2o2 proxy?

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

*hapi: 16.6.2, h2o2: 5.2.0*

I have [h2o2 proxy](https://github.com/hapijs/h2o2) route to use an external API

```
  {
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/api/v3/{param*}',
    handler: {
      proxy: {
        host: 'host.net',
        port: 8100,
        protocol: 'http',
      }   
    }   
  }
```

This API uses the client-side sessions. To maintain a session, a cookie value should be inside a request header, for example:

```
Cookie: SESSION=352abdc5-c0de-49e3-985e-e07c7ab26a88
```

How can I add a cookie value in h2o2?

---

UPDATE.

There is [onRequest](https://github.com/hapijs/h2o2) which should give access to the upstream request. But Node.js throws the error

```
ValidationError: Invalid proxy handler options (/api/v3/{param*}) {
  "host": "host.net",
  "port": 8100,
  "protocol": "http",
  "onRequest" [1]: function onRequest(req) {\n        console.log(req);\n      }
}

[1] "onRequest" is not allowed
```

Comment: `proxy: {
                        host: remoteAddress,
                        port: remotePort || '1337',
                        protocol: 'http',
                        passThrough: true,
                        xforward: true,
                        onRequest: req => { return req; }
                    }`

The above works for me -- `onRequest` triggers an error only if specified outside the `proxy` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mapUri](https://github.com/hapijs/h2o2) method can be used to intercept the upstream request.

Here is an example of the h2o2 proxy route where a cookie is added to the request headers:

```
const host = 'host.net';
const port = 8100;
const protocol = 'http';
const path = '/api/v3/{param*}';
const authCookie = 'SESSION=352abdc5-c0de-49e3-985e-e07c7ab26a88';

export default [
  {
    method: 'GET',
    path,
    handler: {
      proxy: {
        mapUri: function(req, cb) {
          let {path, headers} = req;
          const url = `${protocol}://${host}:${port}${path}`;
          headers.cookie = authCookie;
          return cb(null, url, headers);
        },  
        onResponse: function(err, res, req, reply) {
          return reply(res);
        },  
      },  
    },  
  },
];
```

Comment: I am getting `TypeError: callback is not a function` :(      `"@hapi/h2o2": "^8.3.2"`,

Comment: But what if the header is requested from another URL asynchronously, `mapUri` doesn't seem to support that?